# NavigationMode of ActionBarSherlock doesn't change

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an app that uses ActionBarSherlock. In an activity I have two fragments (**Fragment1** and **Fragment2**). In **Fragment1** I use the following Navigation Mode:

```
getSupportActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

and in **Fragment2**:

```
getSupportActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
```

When I navigate from one fragment to another, everything works fine.

Well, in **Fragment2** I implement a menu option that uses a Collapse Action, that calls an AutoCompleteTextView. When I click at this menu option at **Fragment2** and go back to **Fragment1**, even changing Navigation Mode from standard to list, this change doesn't happen, and the NavigationModeList disappears.

Is this a bug?